# How can I directly update a field by using ng-click AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I trying to add a function: Change a field value on user interface by click on button. Specifically, I want to change `STATUS` field from default value `true` to `false` when I click on button named `DELETE`.

I supposed to use ng-click to call function controller Spring with PUT method.

Here is my code:
1. RestApiController

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}/delete", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<?> changeUserStatus(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody User user){
        logger.info("Change User with id {}", id);
        User currentUser = userService.findById(id);

        if (currentUser == null){
            logger.error("Unable to change. User with id {} not found.", id);
            return new ResponseEntity(new CustomErrorType("Unable to change. User with id " + id + " not found."),
                    HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        currentUser.setStatus(false);
        userService.changeUserStatus(currentUser);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(currentUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

2. UserService.js

```
function changeUserStatus(user, id) {
                console.log('Changing user status with id '+id);
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.put(urls.USER_SERVICE_API + id + "/delete" , user)
                    .then(
                        function (response) {
                            loadAllUsers();
                            deferred.resolve(response.data);
                        },
                        function (errResponse) {
                            console.error('Error while updating User with id :'+id);
                            deferred.reject(errResponse);
                        }
                    );
                return deferred.promise;
            }
```

3. UserController

```
var self = this;

 function changeUserStatus(user, id){
            console.log('About to change user status');
            UserService.changeUserStatus(user, id)
                .then(
                    function (response){
                        console.log('User updated successfully');
                        self.successMessage='User updated successfully';
                        self.errorMessage='';
                        self.done = true;
                        $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
                    },
                    function(errResponse){
                        console.error('Error while updating User');
                        self.errorMessage='Error while updating User '+errResponse.data;
                        self.successMessage='';
                    }
                );
        }
```

4. font-end

```
<div class="panel-heading"><span class="lead">List of Users </span></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>NAME</th>
                        <th>AGE</th>
                        <th>SALARY</th>
                        <th>STATUS</th>
                        <th width="100"></th>
                        <th width="100"></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="u in ctrl.getAllUsers()">
                        <td>{{u.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{u.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{u.age}}</td>
                        <td>{{u.salary}}</td>
                        <td>{{u.status}}</td>
                        <td><button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.changeUserStatus(u.id)" class="btn btn-default custom-width">Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

When I run application and click on `Delete`, it throw this error: `.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "undefined"`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
$http.put(urls.USER_SERVICE_API + id + "/delete" , user)
```

to

```
$http.put(urls.USER_SERVICE_API + "/" + id + "/delete" , user)
```

Your endpoint is `yourapi/user/userId/delete` and not `yourapi/useruserId/delete`

Comment: And is this line in your service `console.log('Changing user status with id '+id);` logging the correct id??

Comment: I cant get the id, it is undefined value now

Comment: That's the problem than. You need to make sure that you are passing the correct id from frontend. Try debugging your code and see why id is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try that